# Use a variable in an Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to use a specific cell as a variable in an excel formula so whatever value is in that cell will be inserted to the formula? For example:

```
=SUM(B1:B100)
```

I want to use cell A2 as my holder, so I insert the end figure there A2 = 95. How do I essentially write this:

```
=SUM(B1:B(A2))
```

So I can leave the formula the same but change the range by updating the value in A2

Comment: Check the function `INDIRECT`. It enables to build a cell address using values in other cells.

Comment: Would the value in A2 be the last row number containing data?  i.e. Are you trying to sum from B1 to the last cell containing data in column B?  If so look at `INDEX` as @Tom Sharpe suggest and `COUNTA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDIRECT` will do it:

```
=SUM(B1:INDIRECT("B1:B"&A2))
```

Comment: Works a treat!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a good way of doing this is to use INDEX. Because INDEX returns a reference, you can use it to specify a range like this

```
=SUM(B1:INDEX(B:B,A2))
```

Although OFFSET and INDIRECT can be used, there are certain disadvantages with these [volatile functions](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/)

Comment: Using the INDIRECT is pretty much exactly what I need, but thank you for telling me about INDEX as that answers another problem I had!